# Trying to convert c# code to the PowerShell version 5 script

Tags: c#, powershell

I have a working c# application. Now I would make a PowerShell script version 5.

I am new to PowerShell scripting. Just tried to find is there any way do it, I found I could do it the following way:-

But I get interpreter error.

My script:-

```
    $Assem = ( 
        "Newtonsoft.Json, version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"    
        ) 


    $Source = @"
    susing Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Schema;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Threading;

    namespace Eurostep.SAS.Bootstrap
    {
        static class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                string file = "host.json"; ;


                JObject json = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(file));

                JToken _;
                if (json.TryGetValue("id", out _) == false)
                {
                    json["id"] = Environment.MachineName;
                }
                JToken systemPathStr;
                if (json.TryGetValue("systemPath", out systemPathStr) == false)
                {
                    systemPathStr = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData), "home", "test");
                }
                DirectoryInfo systemPath = new DirectoryInfo(systemPathStr.ToString());


            }
        }
    }

    "@;

    Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies $Assem -TypeDefinition $Source -Language CSharp
```

I get following error:-

```
    Add-Type : (0) : Metadata file 'Newtonsoft.Json, version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed.dll' could not be
     found
    (1) : susing Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
    At C:\test\test.ps1:59 char:1
    + Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies $Assem -TypeDefinition $Source -Langua ...
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Power...peCompilerError:AddTypeCompilerError) [Add-Type], Exception
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SOURCE_CODE_ERROR,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand

    Add-Type : Cannot add type. Compilation errors occurred.
    At C:\test\test.ps1:59 char:1
    + Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies $Assem -TypeDefinition $Source -Langua ...
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-Type], InvalidOperationException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : COMPILER_ERRORS,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand
```

How can I fix error?

Comment: You have an `s` character before `using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;`. Remove it and your code will compile.

Comment: There is a typo : susing Newtonsoft.Json.Linq; => using

Comment: After typo fix. New error:-  Add-Type : (0) : Metadata file 'Newtonsoft.Json, version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed.dll' could not be found
(1) : 
At C:\practice\try.ps1:46 char:1
+ Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies $Assem -TypeDefinition $Source -Langua ...

Comment: I think I need to know how to load external dll or assembly in the PowerShell script.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found that I have to load the Assembly. There are several ways to do it. But the easiest is to give the actual path of the library as:

```
Add-Type -Path 'C:\thirdparty\Newtonsoft\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'
```